# Italicizing text with ednotes

Tags: footnotes, italic

I am making a critical edition of a text with `ednotes`, attempting to italicize the biblical quotations in the main text while keeping the text which appears in the footnotes un-italicized.

If it's a simple section, placing `\textit` before the `\Anote` command works fine, e.g.
`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[para*, pagewise]{ednotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bigfoot} 

\begin{document}

\textit{
\Anote{
in\< principio erat Verbum et Verbum erat apud Deum et Deus erat \>Verbum
    }{Jn. 1:1}}

\end{document}
```

outputs

> In---Verbum] Jn. 1:1

However, when not all the words in the lemma are biblical, or when lemmas overlap and I need to use `\Anotelabel`, I can't find a solution that keeps the footnote text un-italicized. For example,
`

```
\textit{
\Anotelabel{1}in}\pause{1} principio erat Verbum et Verbum erat apud Deum et Deus erat \resume{1}Verbum\donote{1}{Jn. 1:1}}
```

`

returns the errors:

> misplaced \pause, misplace \resume, misplaced \donote

while

```
 \Anotelabel{1}\textit{in}\pause{1} principio erat Verbum et Verbum erat apud Deum et Deus erat \resume{1}Verbum\donote{1}{Jn. 1:1}}
```

compiles, but outputs

> *in*---Verbum] Jn. 1:1

I am using `miktex` with `texmaker` on windows, if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gonna be tacky and answer my own question.

The answer, given by a friend on another forum, is to use the `\IfLemmaTag` command which works as follows:

```
\Anotelabel{1}\IfLemmaTag{in}{\textit{in}}\pause{1} 
\textit{principio erat Verbum et Verbum erat apud Deum et Deus erat}
\resume{1}\IfLemmaTag{Verbum}{\textit{Verbum}}\donote{1}{Jn. 1:1}
```

That is, `\IfLemmaTag{(Text in note)}{(Text in body)}`

This outputs in the main text:

> *in principio erat Verbum et Verbum erat apud Deum et Deus erat Verbum*

and in the footnote:

> in---Verbum] Jn. 1:1